# Android: getting location using GPS provider returns a wrong location

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm implementing an app that gets your location when you open it. It only gets it when the activity is created, so I don't need a `LocationListener`. I'm testing it in two real devices.

First I try to get the location using `GPS_PROVIDER`. If the result is NULL, I use `NETWORK_PROVIDER`. Since I'm testing it inside a building is to be expected that I won't be able to get the location using the GPS provider.

In one of the devices the location using `GPS_PROVIDER` is NULL, and the `NETWORK_PROVIDER` returns the correct location. But in the other device the location using GPS_PROVIDER is not NULL, but it's wrong (it's in a different city than the one I'm currently am!). This is the code I'm using:

```
private void getPosition() {
    locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    myloc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(myloc == null)
                myloc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if(myloc != null){ 
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try{
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(myloc.getLatitude(), myloc.getLongitude(), 1);

            if(addresses.size()>0){
                String add = "";
                for(int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                    add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i)+"\n";
                placeEdit.setText(add);
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I know the location returned by the GPS provider is wrong? Should I look the network provider first and if it's null use the gps? This app is supposed to be used outside, so I'd like to use the gps first since it's more accurate.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988925/incorrect-gps-location-on-samsung-galaxy2

Comment: Thanks! Now I choose network or GPS depending on the time of the Location, like that post suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As state in [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

> getLastKnownLocation(String provider) 
> Returns a Location
> indicating the data from the last known location fix obtained from the
> given provider.

So when your device obtained position 2h earlier and in the meantime never get fresh fix, Location object return that old position. I suggest you to use `LocationListener` but with thread that will stop listening after some period of time - this approach prevent device from long fix-searching in case of bad view to satellites or when you are inside a building. If `LocationListener` obtain position use it, if not - use `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

Comment: GPS is wheater proof (except the sun disturbs a bit). it should be "in case of bad view to satellites".